# Chrome/Android is prompting to save username on a search input

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Chrome or Android is prompting to save a "username" only (no password) for a text input. I cannot replicate it on desktop.

```
<input placeholder=" &#xf002; Search Name" id="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" type="text">
```

Any ideas how to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the input in a form tag, and it stopped.